# I can't run the "perf" command. Perf is a linux profiler for stack traces

Tags: profiler, perf

Trying to use the perf profiler. I've installed linux generic tools, but no luck. Here is the message I'm getting:

---

```
r@r-K55A:~$ perf
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 3.16.0-45

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-3.16.0-45-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-45-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generic
```

---

I've tried to install the above packages, but I get the following error:

---

```
Unable to locate package linux-tools-3.16.0-45-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-3.16.0-45-generic'
```

---

Comment: So your next step would be to use the internet and confirm that `perf` is indeed going to be found in those package and if the answer is 'yes', then figure out the answer to your second question, which can be consumed by google as "Unable to locate package E: Couldn't find any package by regex" and that has surely been asked an answered many many times

Answer (score 10):

You can safely use this snippet:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Now only `linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic` are needed, optionally `linux-cloud-tools-generic`. `linux-tools-$(uname -r)` is just for a specific kernel version. At least is what I interpret of the message if only `linux-tools-common` is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I could never get it working. Updated my Kernal to newest stable version and tried to download the above packages from sudo apt-get install. I finally found the packages manually online, and it's working fine.